What evidence was there, in Old Testament times, that the sacrifices being performed would be realised, actually, in the offering up of a humanity?
The complexity and intricacy of the whole array of sacrifices instituted in the wilderness as the children of Israel were instructed to do so, is , in retrospect, clearly a setting forth of all that Christ suffered, expressed in various ways and by different means.
The wave offering, the heave offering, the burnt offering, the sin offering : all demonstrate different aspects of the sufferings and death of Christ at Golgotha.
But what is there in the Old Testament writings that would have given someone at that time the prospect to look forward to, that, eventually, in God's own time, they would all be realised in the offering up of a humanity ?
I say 'offering up of a humanity' as I am being careful in the way I express the matter of the humanity and the Deity of Jesus Christ, the Son of God and because I am seeking a response on the basis of Trinitarian Protestantism.

@Nigel - do you have any clarification between the wave offering and the heave offering? They look like possibly the same thing, or if they were different, it is a point of confusion even to the translators.

Sacrifices acceptable to God had to meet stringent requirements. Sticking only to animal sacrifices in this answer, I think of a few special OT ones that could have spoken to observers of God’s future plan for a super-human sacrifice that would deal with the sin of humanity, once and for all. Those in later generations who did not witness those rare events, would read them as recorded in the Hebrew scriptures. A few ‘clues’ along the way:

Abel’s accepted sacrifice of a lamb – with God’s promise in Gen.3:15 of a ‘seed’ of deliverance to come, fresh in the mind of this second-born son of Adam and Eve.

Job’s sacrifices on behalf of his children, which did not prevent their deaths or his suffering – then his prophetic statement of faith in a future Redeemer – Job 9:25

Abraham’s willingness to sacrifice his child of promise, with fire in his hand to light the wood, but God providing a ram in lieu. “God will provide.”

Manoah’s sacrifice of a meat offering, the flame ascended to heaven with the angel of the Lord going up in it. This with regard to a conception of a male-child who would deliver Israel.

The passover lamb was kept in the house (a week or more?) It lived closely alongside them. It was one of the family.  And then they killed it.

Amos prophesying “I hate, I despise your feast days… I will not accept [your offerings]… But let judgment run down as waters, and righteousness as a mighty stream…  I saw the Lord standing upon the altar: and he said, Smite the lintel of the door, that the posts may shake, and cut them in the head…” But after the Lord’s sifting, he raises up the fallen tabernacle of David – a miraculous deliverance. Surely this showed a greater than David?

One was foretold to come who would turn their hearts; they would be given new hearts, and a new covenant would be initiated by God himself. Ezekiel 37:24, “And David my servant shall be king over them” (though king David was bone-dead by then.)


With that over-view of the OT, looking through the book of Leviticus then takes on massive significance. In chapter 1 alone are crucial words regarding God’s prescribed sacrifices which point towards what occurred at Golgotha, on the day in which “the Passover must be killed”. Christ is the Lamb slain from the foundation of the world. And, ascended, he is still the Lamb. All was restored to God’s original purpose by the obedience of the Lamb, as a subject son to a father; and that forevermore. He is the ascending. He is the counterpart to the church, upon the wood (the tree). He braved God’s all-consuming fire of judgment of sin.
Through the offering of himself was resolved the impossibility of outraged and contradicted Divine nature ever being in union with transgressing and disobedient human nature. But I see this as a Christian, retrospectively. The question asks how Israel of old could have seen evidence of what God’s system of sacrifices signified regarding a redeemed humanity.
This hazy answer suggests, only by obedience, one step at a time. Only by hearing God speak – as did a few of the people of faith in the OT. Only by considering the prophecies about the coming One, the Messiah and relating them to the sacrificial system. Isaiah’s prophecies in particular spoke of the suffering of that Servant’s death (Isa.59:20).  Only by it dawning on generations of people making those sacrifices that that system did not save them; it showed up their continual sin year on year, yet through it God was being gracious to them, with an immense deliverance yet to come, miraculously, raising up one like unto Moses – Deuteronomy 18:15-19. Moses and Elijah appeared alongside Jesus on the mount of transfiguration.

I will string a few verses together and comment briefly for, in my opinion, they need little embellishment for a connection to be drawn in answer to this good question.

For thus saith the LORD, Ye have sold yourselves for nought; and ye shall be redeemed without money. - Isaiah 52:3

Sold into idolatry and slavery to sin for no gain to yourselves.  Redeemed without cost to yourselves.

The LORD hath made bare his holy arm in the eyes of all the nations; and all the ends of the earth shall see the salvation of our God. - Isaiah 52:10

It is the Lord Himself who brings about salvation and it is not done in nor kept secret from the whole world.

So shall he sprinkle many nations; the kings shall shut their mouths at him: for that which had not been told them shall they see; and that which they had not heard shall they consider. Who hath believed our report? and to whom is the arm of the LORD revealed?- Isaiah 52:15 - 53:1

Sprinkling of atonement done by the (human) servant of the Lord who, himself, is the bared, holy arm of the Lord.

But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his stripes we are healed. All we like sheep have gone astray; we have turned every one to his own way; and the LORD hath laid on him the iniquity of us all. - Isaiah 53:5-6

One human substituted for all humanity. One who is both atoning sacrifice and sin-bearing scapegoat as pre-figured in law and temple.

Yet it pleased the LORD to bruise him; he hath put him to grief: when thou shalt make his soul an offering for sin, he shall see his seed, he shall prolong his days, and the pleasure of the LORD shall prosper in his hand. He shall see of the travail of his soul, and shall be satisfied: by his knowledge shall my righteous servant justify many; for he shall bear their iniquities. Therefore will I divide him a portion with the great, and he shall divide the spoil with the strong; because he hath poured out his soul unto death: and he was numbered with the transgressors; and he bare the sin of many, and made intercession for the transgressors. - Isaiah 53:10-12

The Lord is thus pleased.  Not in human sacrifice itself but in the laying down of a righteous humanity for the redemption of an unrighteous:  One spotless representative of that which is to be cleansed.
Not at any cost to the unrighteous humanity.  Not at any cost to the humanity we possess (so says Isaiah 52:3) but it is paid by a humanity nonetheless.  What manner of humanity then, which does not exist on the earth; who is this King of Glory who can go for us into God's presence with a pleasing sacrifice?

Who shall ascend into the hill of the LORD? or who shall stand in his holy place? He that hath clean hands, and a pure heart; who hath not lifted up his soul unto vanity, nor sworn deceitfully. He shall receive the blessing from the LORD, and righteousness from the God of his salvation. This is the generation of them that seek him, that seek thy face, O Jacob. Selah. - Psalm 24:-6

He shall be a righteous man.

Lift up your heads, O ye gates; and be ye lift up, ye everlasting doors; and the King of glory shall come in. Who is this King of glory? The LORD strong and mighty, the LORD mighty in battle. Lift up your heads, O ye gates; even lift them up, ye everlasting doors; and the King of glory shall come in. Who is this King of glory? The LORD of hosts, he is the King of glory. Selah. - Psalm 24:7-10

He shall be Jehovah Himself.
Jehovah God, who established the world and the fulness thereof, shall come in a new humanity, a righteous humanity, and by self-sacrifice shall redeem unrighteous man (who sold themselves unto vanity) at no cost to themselves.  This one counted the cost from the foundation of the world and then built:  He shall never be put to shame.
This is the Gospel of Jesus Christ.  Foretold, pre-figured, manifest in time and flesh, and soon to be brought to consummation: God, in Christ, reconciling the world unto Himself.
"Who hath believed our report? and to whom is the arm of the LORD revealed?"  He who has ears to hear, let him hear.

The book of Genesis, which Jewish tradition ascribes authorship to Moses, is vital to understanding the rest of the Pentateuch. Beyond the explicit prophecies therein that are fulfilled in the later books, many of the figures and events that occur within the book of Genesis are symbolic precursors of what is to come. Similarly, by discovering the parrallels between Genesis and the subsequent events in the Pentateuch, we can better understand Genesis.
Of particular relevance here, I think, is the story of Abel & Cain in Genesis 4. First, let us note some striking similarities between Abel and the Aaronic Priesthood. Abel sacrificed the firstborn from his herd, and offered to God the fatty portions (Genesis 4:4).
As I'm sure you know, the firstborn male of every womb belongs to the LORD (Exodus 13:2; 13:12). For clean animals, like the oxen, goats, and lambs, they were to be sacrificed and eaten in the LORD's presence (Exodus 13:15; Deutoronomy 12:17-18; Deuteronomy 14:23; Deuteronomy 15:19-20). However, unclean animals were to be redeemed (Numbers 18:15). The firstborn male of oxen, goats and lambs specifically could not be redeemed for they are considered holy (Numbers 18:17).
In general, Israel was not allowed to eat the fat of Oxen, Goats, or Lambs (Leviticus 7:23). The priests were also forbidden from eating the fat of these animals - but were required to burn it as an offering of smoke to the LORD (Numbers 18:17). Thus the best portions of the holy firstborn were reserved for the LORD; a tithe of the tithe and the holy of holies as it were.
It is also worth noting that the LORD promises as part of the Covenant that he would dwell with Israel and walk among them (Leviticus 26:11-12). Although they are not in the Garden, the LORD yet still walked and talked with Adam, Eve, Abel and Cain at the start of Genesis 4.
So then, Abel sacrificed to the LORD in a manner consistent with the subsequent Priesthood. He slew the firstborn of his flock and offered the best part - the fat - to the LORD, whilst presumably eating the meat himself (and potentially with family). God had regard for Abel and his sacrifice, for doing what was right, and thus Abel was deemed righteous (Genesis 4:4-7; Matthew 23:35, Hebrews 11:4).
On the other hand, Cain is like Israel when they fall away from the LORD - cast out of the LORD's presence and made to wander. For the curse of the Law is that when Israel falls away, they will persecuted by other nations and driven out of the land where the LORD dwells (Deutoronomy 28:15-68), but because the LORD is faithful he would never completely destroy them - but their numbers would be seriously reduced (Deuteronomy 28:62). Similarly, Cain is given a mark to protect him from being killed (Genesis 4:15) - and this despite the fact that the Law demands the death of a murderer (Numbers 35:31).
However, the LORD would not permit his righteous line to be extinguished. And so he blessed Eve with Seth, whom Eve says that God gave her in place of Abel (Genesis 4:25). And so as early as Genesis 4 we see the principles of substitutionary sacrifice at play, and with human lives no less.
It is also worth noting that of all the three sons said to be born to Adam and Eve, only Seth is said to have been born in the image and likeness of Adam, who was in turn made in the image and likeness of God (Genesis 5:3).
Now then, let us consider Yom Kippur - the Day of Atonement (Leviticus 16). The High Priest takes two goats and casts lots for them. One is selected for sacrifice and one as the scapegoat. The blood of the sacrificed goat is a sin offering for the people and is used to make atonement for the Holy Place (Leviticus 16:15-19). Afterwards, the High Priest takes the scapegoat, puts his hands on it and confesses all of Israel's sins. The goat is then taken to the wilderness and let go so that it can carry the sins of Israel away to an isolated territory (Leviticus 16:20-22).
Although the connection is not explicit, we can see clear parallels between Yom Kippur and the story of Abel & Cain; where Abel is like the goat selected as a sin offering and Cain is like the scapegoat cast out of the LORD's presence and made to wander the wilderness, carrying the sin away. Israel, ideally, parallels Seth in Yom Kippur - the son given in place of righteous Abel, made in the image and likeness of Adam who is in the image and likeness of God.
Finally, let us consider Christ. Like Abel, Christ was a righteous individual who served as a sin offering, offering up to God a holy sacrifice. Barabbas is like Cain & the scapegoat - a murderer set free. And through Christ we have been given the right to be as Seth - the children given in place of the death of the righteous son, born (again) in the image and likeness of God.
At least, this is my interpretation :)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

My edit was merely to correct a typo [& in place of 'of', 2nd para.]
